# How can I design this concept in a object oriented manner?

Tags: java, oop

I am having a bit of issues with design. Maybe I am thinking about this all wrong, but it seems that what I am designing only works well in a procedural manner.

#### The Game

I am working on a game, this game has about 10-20 players inside of it, and consists of 3 rounds. When players start up the game, the server loads their data from a database, stores it in a java class, and sends data that is requested to the client. Lets call this `Player.java`. This class is persistent in between the rounds of the game.
Every player in the game also has a role. This role changes in-between each round and I need this role to be linked with `Player.java` in some way. Right now I have 3 roles: **Hunter**, **Seeker**, and **Spectator**. Each role has the same basic things: `onDeath()`, `onRespawn()`, `onKill(KillEvent event)`. I also need to be able to easily check what role a player is. (For example linking the roles with a enum).

#### The Problem

The problem I am running into now is how do I implement this in a OOP way? Originally, I had each role as a class that implements `Role.java`, and every time a role is created, it takes a `Player` in the constructor. This is all fine and dandy until I start changing people's roles in the middle of the rounds and after the end of each round. It seems like bad practice to me if I am consistently setting the players role to a new object.

#### Summary

To sum this up (since I am terrible at describing things), it seems like all of this would work perfectly in a procedural manner, but I can't figure out for the life of me a good way to implement this concept using OOP. The way I have it implemented now, each `Player` has a enum stating what role they are, and to change that role I simply change the enum in `Player`. With that being said though, once I get to the game logic, I end up with a TON of nested if statements, something that I feel could be greatly reduced with some polymorphism.

So to end with a question, what would be a good plan of attack to implement this (or a slightly modified version of this system) in a object oriented way without having to consistently create new objects that take in data from old objects? (I don't have a ton of experience with OOP, but to me this just seems like a bad idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would go for this solution:

- Make `Player` an Interface
- Create a Proxy-Class for it (a class that has only one property, which is of type Player, and redirects all methods to this object). Lets call it `ConcretePlayer`
- Add a `setRole` method, taking a Role to `ConcretePlayer`.
- Make `Role` implement `Player`
- Create Subclasses of `Role` like you did, each takes a `ConcretePlayer` in their constructor.
- Store the stats that are shared among all Roles in the `ConcretePlayer`
- Externally use `Player` or `ConcretePlayer` to access everything.

It's not fleshed out perfectly, but I think you get the idea. You may find that `Role` and `Player` shouldn't share the same interface, or that you want to create an own interface for the callbacks, but that depends on the rest of your code and usecases.

Comment: As someone who understands most concepts in java, but doesn't understand how to solve problems using these concepts, this is brilliant. Do you know of any good books or e-books that could help me out? I understand most java and OOP concepts, I just don't know how to use them in useful ways. (if that makes sense).

Comment: There is a lot on design patterns out there, Wikipedia is quite good http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern. But when it comes to actually using them there is no way around experience. If you look through the list you will find alot of apealing things, but frankly you will probably overuse them at first. You know, if you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail, and that's very true for design patterns.

Comment: @Phiction: I have a question about the answer above. Role shouldn't implement Player as it does not follow the "is-a" relationship rule nor the Liskov Substitution Principle. Better would be for Player to "have-a" Role which helps define its behavior, and allow a Player to swap Roles if need be via setter objects.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ment by "You may find that Role and Player shouldn't share the same interface". But you phrased that much better ;D